# Scroll to the first error field and also display error message in all other fields

Tags: angularjs

Following is my code.
I want to scroll to the first error field which is not filed when the save function invoked even if there are many error fields.But error message must be shown in all fields. There will be n number of rows to the table.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function PeopleCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.people = [];

   $scope.people = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "a",
      valid:true
    },
{
    id: 2,
    name: "b",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 3,
    name: "c",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 4,
    name: "d",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 5,
    name: "e",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 6,
    name: "f",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 7,
    name: "g",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 8,
    name: "h",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 9,
    name: "i",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 10,
    name: "j",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 11,
    name: "k",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 12,
    name: "l",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 13,
    name: "m",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 14,
    name: "n",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 15,
    name: "o",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 16,
    name: "p",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 17,
    name: "q",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 18,
    name: "r",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 19,
    name: "s",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 20,
    name: "t",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 21,
    name: "u",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 22,
    name: "v",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 23,
    name: "w",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 24,
    name: "x",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 25,
    name: "y",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 26,
    name: "z",
      valid:true}
];
      
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #666;   
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
  font-weight: bold;    
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
<button ng-click="saveData()">Save</button>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td><input ng-model="person.age">
        <p ng-hide="person.valid">
        <span>Please fill the field</span>
        </p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

This is a sample example created for stack, i will implement the methods suggesting in my actual code. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here I have a solution. Thank you.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function PeopleCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.people = [];

   $scope.people = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "a",
      valid:true
    },
{
    id: 2,
    name: "b",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 3,
    name: "c",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 4,
    name: "d",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 5,
    name: "e",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 6,
    name: "f",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 7,
    name: "g",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 8,
    name: "h",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 9,
    name: "i",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 10,
    name: "j",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 11,
    name: "k",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 12,
    name: "l",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 13,
    name: "m",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 14,
    name: "n",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 15,
    name: "o",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 16,
    name: "p",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 17,
    name: "q",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 18,
    name: "r",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 19,
    name: "s",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 20,
    name: "t",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 21,
    name: "u",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 22,
    name: "v",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 23,
    name: "w",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 24,
    name: "x",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 25,
    name: "y",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 26,
    name: "z",
      valid:true}
];
$scope.saveData = function(){
var j=0;

for(var i=0;i<$scope.people.length;i++){
if($scope.people[i].age==undefined){
$scope.people[i].valid = false;
if(j==0){
console.log($scope.people[i].id);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#'+$scope.people[i].id).position().top-25}, 0);

j++;
}
}
}
}
      
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #666;   
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
  font-weight: bold;    
    padding: 2px;
}
.error{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
<button ng-click="saveData()">Save</button>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td><input id="{{person.id}}" ng-model="person.age">
        <p ng-hide="person.valid">
        <span class="error">Please fill the field</span>
        </p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function PeopleCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.people = [];

   $scope.people = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "a",
      valid:true
    },
{
    id: 2,
    name: "b",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 3,
    name: "c",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 4,
    name: "d",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 5,
    name: "e",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 6,
    name: "f",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 7,
    name: "g",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 8,
    name: "h",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 9,
    name: "i",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 10,
    name: "j",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 11,
    name: "k",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 12,
    name: "l",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 13,
    name: "m",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 14,
    name: "n",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 15,
    name: "o",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 16,
    name: "p",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 17,
    name: "q",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 18,
    name: "r",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 19,
    name: "s",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 20,
    name: "t",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 21,
    name: "u",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 22,
    name: "v",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 23,
    name: "w",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 24,
    name: "x",
      valid:true},    {
    id: 25,
    name: "y",
      valid:true},
{
    id: 26,
    name: "z",
      valid:true}
];
$scope.saveData = function(){
var j=0;

for(var i=0;i<$scope.people.length;i++){
if($scope.people[i].age==undefined){
$scope.people[i].valid = false;
if(j==0){
console.log($scope.people[i].id);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#'+$scope.people[i].id).position().top}, 0);

j++;
}
}
}
}
      
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #666;   
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
  font-weight: bold;    
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
<button ng-click="saveData()">Save</button>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td><input id="{{person.id}}" ng-model="person.age">
        <p ng-hide="person.valid">
        <span class="error">Please fill the field</span>
        </p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```